# Sinatra doesn’t know this ditty

Tags: ruby, sinatra

Would anyone check if I have done something wrong?

**My app.rb:**

```
require 'sinatra/base'
require 'sinatra/flash'
require './lib/hangperson_game.rb'

class HangpersonApp < Sinatra::Base
  enable :sessions
  register Sinatra::Flash

  before do
    @game = session[:game] || HangpersonGame.new('')
  end

  after do
    session[:game] = @game
  end

  get '/' do
    redirect '/new'
  end

  get '/new' do
    erb :new
    #"Hello World!"
  end

  post '/create' do
    @game = HangpersonGame.new(word)
    redirect '/show'
  end

  post '/guess' do
    letter = params[:guess].to_s[0]
    begin
      if letter.nil? || letter.empty? || !((letter=~/^[A-z]$/) == 0)
        flash[:message] = "Invalid guess." 
      elsif !(@game.guess(letter))
        flash[:message] = "You have already used that letter."
      end
    end
    redirect '/show'
  end

  get '/show' do
    ### YOUR CODE HERE ###
    if (@game.check_win_or_lose == :win)
      redirect '/win'
    elsif (@game.check_win_or_lose == :lose)
      redirect '/lose'
    else
      erb :show 
    end
  end

  get '/win' do
    ### YOUR CODE HERE ###
    if (@game.check_win_or_lose != :win)
      redirect '/show'
    else
      erb :win 
    end
  end

  get '/lose' do
    if (@game.check_win_or_lose != :lose)
      redirect '/show'
    else
      erb :lose 
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: What triggered the error?

Comment: We need more info. Do any of the routes work? How do you run your app? Could be something related to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28005566/sinatra-doesnt-know-this-ditty-even-when-default-route-is-implemented-with-modu), but that's just a shot in the dark.

Comment: Hi Chit Siu, welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so we can better help you.

Comment: I run it Could9, using the command $rerun -- rackup -p $PORT -o $IP

Comment: More info:
Show game state, allow player to enter guess; may redirect to Win or Lose GET /show
Display form that can generate `POST /create` GET /new
Start new game; redirects to Show Game after changing state POST /create
Process guess; redirects to Show Game after changing state POST /guess
Show "you win" page with button to start new game GET /win
Show "you lose" page with button to start new game GET /lose

Comment: the /new is working, but when I click on a button which should direct me to /create then /show, the error pops up

Comment: Please share your `new` view.

Comment: @Gerry `<!-- This form is incomplete--it needs a destination URL as well as a method: -->
<form method="post">
  <input type="submit" value="New Game"/>
</form>`

Comment: @ChitSiu And the error shows when you hit `submit`, right?

Comment: The show.erb:
`<h2>Guess a letter</h2>

<% if flash[:message] %>
  <p>
    <span class="error"><%= flash[:message] %></span>
  </p>
<% end %>

<p>
  Wrong Guesses:
  <span class="guesses"><%= @game.wrong_guesses %></span>
</p>

<p>
  Word so far:
  <span class="word"><%= @game.word_with_guesses %></span>
</p>

<form action="/guess" method="post">
  <input type="text" size="1" name="guess" autocomplete="off"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Guess!"/>
</form>

<%= erb :new %>`

Comment: @Gerry when I hit the button in [link](https://ibb.co/cmCWck)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are not giving any `action` (i.e. *url*) to the `form`, so when you click on `New Game` button, it sends the information back to itself, that is to `new` action, but using `POST` instead of `GET`, thus giving you that error.

Add the `action` you need (i assume is `/create`) in the form within `new` view, like this:

```
<form method="post" action="/create">
  <input type="submit" value="New Game"/>
</form>
```

This way, after you click `New Game`, the form will be sent to `create` action.

Answer (score 1):

If you create modular style Sinatra application, (can [read about it here](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/sinatra-up-and/9781449306847/ch04.html)), you should to declare this row in THE END of your class (inside of it):

```
run! if app_file == $0
```

now you can use `ruby my_modular/application.rb` to run your app as well as `rackup -p 4567`