# Minitest with Sinatra (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, testing, sinatra, rack, minitest

I'm trying to use minitest with sintara and my issue is that running the test (ruby test_login.rb) is unable to find the login page and when I print out the document html I get the sinatra 404 page. I have no idea how to connect my web app with this test program and all documentation and previous questions I have scoured have nothing that helps me.

Here is my code:

```
require 'sinatra/base'
require 'minitest/autorun'
require 'rack/test'
require 'minitest/spec'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'rack/test'
require_relative 'login'

class Test < MiniTest::Test`

  include Rack::Test::Methods

  def app
    Sinatra::Application
  end

  def test_login
    response = get ('/home')
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(response.body)
    puts last_response
    puts doc
    #response = post '/login', username: 'test_user', password: 'password'
    #get '/home'
    #follow_redirect!()
    #puts doc
    #assert_equal "Admin", doc.at_css("#admin-block div h1")
  end
end
```

Please do not comment asking me to use a different testing gem.

Thank you

Comment: You should probably show at least some relevant parts of your Sinatra application. Since (I assume) `response = get ('/home')` works, I guess this is not a problem with Minitest or Rack::Test, but with the app itself.

Comment: response = get ('/home') is not working properly because the output to console is getting a 404 page, it should be getting the home page.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're testing that the login works, you only want to see if the login information that you pass to the login form actually gives a `HTTP 200` response.

There is no need for the first part of the code that is not commented in your example.
As a side-note, checking if a response from a page has a certain HTTP code with content of the page body is not considered a 'good' test, but if you consider it to be decent enough, then go ahead with it.

The following test should work if the login information that you pass is valid.

```
def test_login
  response = post '/login', username: 'test_user', password: 'password'
  assert_equal response.status, Net::HTTPSuccess
end
```

**EDIT**

Update to the question came right after posting my answer, but if you're getting an error when sending a GET request to `/home` it sounds like that route is not defined in your application.

Comment: 1) Error:
    Test#test_login:
    NameError: uninitialized constant Test::Net
        test_login.rb:31:in `test_login'

Is the error I receive.

`assert_equal response.status, Net::HTTPSuccess` is the offending piece of code.

Comment: You would have to `require 'net/http'` for this to work.

Comment: Back to original problem: 404






# Running:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <style type="text/css">
  body { text-align:center;font-family:helvetica,arial;font-size:22px;
    color:#888;margin:20px}
  #c {margin:0 auto;width:500px;text-align:left}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <h2>Sinatra doesn’t know this ditty.</h2>
  <img src="http://example.org/__sinatra__/404.png">
  <div id="c">
    Try this:
    <pre>post '/login' do
  "Hello World"
end
</pre>
  </div>
</body>
</html>

Comment: This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28005566/sinatra-doesnt-know-this-ditty-even-when-default-route-is-implemented-with-modu) might be related to this problem.